# Assembly x86 - Mouse cursor hides drawn pixels

Tags: assembly

I am currently creating a windows-like paint in asm x86.

I have a procedure which creates a line between two points. The input is the mouse location where you left-click.

The problem is, whenever I draw the line, the pixels which are positioned beneath the shown cursor are deleted.

How can I fix it?

Code:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
input db 6 dup (0)
FirstPointX dw ?
FirstPointY dw ?
CurrentPointX dw ?
CurrentPointY dw ?
LineDown    db  13,10,'$'

CODESEG
y           equ [word bp+16]
x           equ [word bp+14]
StepVal     equ [word bp+12]
deltaY      equ [word bp+10]
deltaX      equ [word bp+8]
x2          equ [word bp+6]
y2          equ [word bp+4]


proc FreePolygon
    push bp
    mov di,1h

        MouseLP:
        mov ax,3h
        int 33h
        and bx,1h
        cmp bx, 1h ; check left mouse click
        jne MouseLP
        WaitForMouseRelease:

        int 33h
        cmp bx,1h
        je WaitForMouseRelease
        shr cx,1 ; adjust cx to range 0-319, to fit screen
        sub dx, 1 ; move one pixel, so the pixel will not be hidden by mouse
        mov bh,0h
        mov al,4
        mov ah,0Ch
        int 10h
        cmp di,1h
        jne notFirstPoint
        mov [FirstPointX],cx
        mov [FirstPointY],dx
        mov [CurrentPointX],cx
        mov [CurrentPointY],dx
        notFirstPoint:
        push cx
        push dx
        dec di

        call Line
        ;mov ax,02h
        ;int 33h
        mov [CurrentPointX],cx
        mov [CurrentPointY],dx
        jmp MouseLP
    EndFreePolygon:
    push cx
    push dx
    mov ax,[FirstPointX]
    mov [CurrentPointX],ax
    mov ax,[FirstPointY]
    mov [CurrentPointY],ax
    call Line
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bp
    ret
endp FreePolygon


proc Line

    push bp
    mov bp,sp
    mov ax,[CurrentPointX]
    cmp ax,x2
    jng StartLine
    mov ax,x2
    mov bx,[CurrentPointX]
    mov x2,bx
    mov [CurrentPointX],ax
    mov ax,y2
    mov bx,[CurrentPointY]
    mov [CurrentPointY],ax
    mov y2,bx
    StartLine:
    mov StepVal,0
    mov ax,y2
    sub ax,[CurrentPointY]
    mov deltaY,0
    add deltaY,ax
    mov ax,x2
    sub ax,[CurrentPointX]
    mov deltaX,0
    add deltaX,ax
    cmp ax,deltaY
    jg above
    jmp less
    above:
        mov ax,[CurrentPointY]
        cmp ax,y2
        jng PosAbove
        NegAbove:
            mov ax,[CurrentPointY]
            mov y,ax
            mov ax,[CurrentPointX]
            mov x,ax
            forAboveX:
            mov ax,deltaY
            sub StepVal,ax
            mov ax,StepVal
            cmp ax,deltaX
            jl lessDeltaX
            dec y
            mov ax,deltaX
            sub StepVal,ax
            lessDeltaX:
            xor bl,bl
            push cx
            push dx
            mov cx,x
            mov dx,y
            mov ax,0c04h
            int 10h
            pop dx
            pop cx
            mov ax,x
            cmp ax,x2
            jg endLineNegAbove
            inc x
            jmp forAboveX
            endLineNegAbove:
            pop bp
            ret
        PosAbove:
            mov ax,[CurrentPointY]
            mov y,ax
            mov ax,[CurrentPointX]
            mov x,ax
            forAboveX2:
            mov ax,deltaY
            add StepVal,ax
            mov ax,StepVal
            cmp ax,deltaX
            jl lessDeltaX2
            inc y
            mov ax,deltaX
            sub StepVal,ax
            lessDeltaX2:
            xor bl,bl
            push cx
            push dx
            mov cx,x
            mov dx,y
            mov ax,0c04h
            int 10h
            pop dx
            pop cx
            mov ax,x
            cmp ax,x2
            endLine2:
            jg endLinePosAbove
            inc x
            jmp forAboveX2
            endLinePosAbove:
            pop bp
            ret
    less:
        mov ax,[CurrentPointY]
        cmp ax,y2
        jng PosLess
        NegLess:
            mov ax,[CurrentPointX]
            mov x,ax
            mov ax,[CurrentPointY]
            mov y,ax
            forLessX:
            mov ax,deltaX
            add StepVal,ax
            mov ax,StepVal
            cmp ax,deltaY
            jl lessDeltaY
            inc x
            mov ax,deltaY
            add StepVal,ax
            lessDeltaY2:
            xor bl,bl
            push cx
            push dx
            mov cx,x
            mov dx,y
            mov ax,0c04h
            int 10h
            pop dx
            pop cx
            mov ax,y
            cmp ax,y2
            endLine3:
            jg endLineNegLess
            inc y
            jmp forLessX
            endLineNegLess:
            pop bp
            ret
        PosLess:
            mov ax,[CurrentPointX]
            mov x,ax
            mov ax,[CurrentPointY]
            mov y,ax
            forLessX2:
            mov ax,deltaX
            add StepVal,ax
            mov ax,StepVal
            cmp ax,deltaY
            jl lessDeltaY
            inc x
            mov ax,deltaY
            sub StepVal,ax
            lessDeltaY:
            xor bl,bl
            push cx
            push dx
            mov cx,x
            mov dx,y
            mov ax,0c04h
            int 10h
            pop dx
            pop cx
            mov ax,y
            cmp ax,y2
            jg endLinePosLess
            inc y
            jmp forLessX2
            endLinePosLess:
            pop bp
            ret
endp Line

start:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov ax, 13h
int 10h
;Graphic mode

mov ax,0h
int 33h
; Show mouse
mov ax,1h
int 33h




    call FreePolygon


    ;Wait for key press
    mov ah,00h
    int 16h
    ;Return to text mode



    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 2
    int 10h
    ; Return to text mode
exit:
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
END start
```

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score 3):

Mouse drivers for old graphics modes are not as advanced as current ones. They copy the area below the mouse pointer, draw the mouse on top, and when you move the mouse the old area is copied back; then, the process is repeated for the new position. This happens inside an interrupt and so you cannot determine when the mouse gets re-drawn and is (shortly) not visible.

The solution is to hide the mouse before you access the screen (writing *or* reading) and show it again when done. From [Ralf Brown's Interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm):

```
; Hide mouse:
mov ax, 2
int 33h
.. your line drawing code here ..
; Show mouse:
mov ax, 1
int 33h
```

You can decide for yourself when to hide and show the mouse: before calling your own low level drawing routines, or inside each of the routines. You can even do both for safety. Hiding the mouse pointer multiple times is not a problem as it keeps a counter, and you need the same number of "Show" calls before it gets drawn again.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use an own PS2-mouse-handler for self drawing our own mouse-pointer to the screen like the Cutemouse-driver. http://cutemouse.sourceforge.net/

The IRQhandler below need to add some instrunctions for to store the movement/clicks into a known memory location and our main routine have to draw the mouse pointer and to copyback the old area of the screen and so the shape of our own mouse pointer can have any size, form and color of the used videomode (example it can also be used for 32 bit true color videomodes with a widescreen resolution using the linear framebuffer together with the VESA-VBE-Bios: vbe3.pdf from vesa.org).

(Hint for using an USB-mouse: Enable "USB legacy" inside of the mainboard bios, this will redirect the USB-data of an USB mouse into the keyboard controller, so it can be used like a PS2-mouse.)

```
checkPS2:
int 11h         ; get equipment list
test    al, 3
jz  noPS2       ; jump if PS/2-Mouse not indicated
mov bh,3
mov     ax, 0C205h
int 15h             ; initialize mouse, bh=datasize
jc noPS2
mov bh,3
mov     ax, 0C203h
int 15h             ; set mouse resolution bh
jc noPS2
mov     ax, cs
mov     es, ax
mov bx, OFFSET PS2dummy
mov     ax, 0C207h
int 15h             ; mouse, es:bx=ptr to handler
jc noPS2
xor     bx, bx
mov     es, bx      ; mouse, es:bx=ptr to handler
mov     ax, 0C207h
int 15h
ret

noPS2:
stc
ret

PS2dummy:
retf
;---------------------------------------------------------
enablePS2:
call disablePS2
mov    ax, cs
mov    es, ax
mov    bx, OFFSET IRQhandler
mov    ax, 0C207h   ; es:bx=ptr to handler
int 15h
mov bh,1        ; set mouse on
mov     ax, 0C200h
int 15h
ret
;-------------------------------
disablePS2:
xor bx, bx      ; set mouse off
mov ax, 0C200h
int 15h
xor     bx, bx
mov     es, bx
mov     ax, 0C207h  ; es:bx=ptr to handler
int 15h
ret
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IRQhandler:
    assume  ds:nothing,es:nothing
cld
push   ds
push   es
pusha
mov     ax, cs
mov     ds, ax
mov     bp, sp
mov     al, [bp+24+6] ; buttons
mov     bl, al
shl     al, 3         ; CF=Y sign bit
sbb     ch, ch        ; signed extension 9->16 bit
cbw                   ; extend X sign bit
mov     al, [bp+24+4] ; AX=X movement
mov     cl, [bp+24+2] ; CX=Y movement
xchg    bx, ax
neg     cx            ; reverse Y movement
popa
pop     es
pop     ds
retf
```